# Wildfly, Tomcat, Apache and Subdomains

Tags: apache, ubuntu, tomcat, subdomain, wildfly

I have an Ubuntu server in AWS that is running multiple application servers -- a Wildfly serving up some pages and two Tomcats running a separate app.

I am trying to get subdomains working.

I have DNS's set up to point subdomain1.example.com, subdomain2.example.com.  That works fine.

Wildfly is listening on port 80 (I think?), the Tomcats are listening on 8080 and 8090.  The goal is to have www.example.com go to Wildfly, subdomain1.example.com go to Tomcat : 8080 and subdomain2.example.com go to Tomcat : 8090

I've found numerous posts that talk about setting up virtual hosts in Apache that should solve my problem.  But I keep getting sent down rabbit holes.  Some suggest adding to `/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin/httpd.config` and some suggest putting it in `/opt/bitnami/apache2/sites-available/subdomain1.example.com.conf`

My first issue:   I don't think that Apache is even running.  I was under the impression that Apache was baked into Wildfly, but when I execute:

```
service apache2 status
```

I get:

> apache2.service
>      Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
>      Active: inactive (dead)

Running `sudo service --status-all` also doesn't show it running so I think that it is not.  It seems to be installed (Bitnami stack) in `/opt/bitnami/apache2`

Do I have to turn Apache on as part of Wildfly (and how to turn it on)?  If I do, then I would assume that Wildfly is no longer getting traffic.

Second - my research tells me I need i need to enable `proxy` and `proxy_http` using `a2enmod` and `a2ensite` but I don't have these.  Research suggests that all Ubuntu's will have those scripts... do they get created if I turn on Apache?

Sorry for all the noob questions.... I'm a developer without a DevOps guy.  This seems like it would so common it would be baked in or there would be a definite solution that I am probably missing.

Comment: Based on your post you're running a Bitnami image.  Unfortunately it's a bit tough to decode what has and hasn't been installed based on that.  A "normal" Ubuntu with the `apache2` package installed will have `a2enmod` and `a2ensite`.   What Bitnami image are you using?  Ultimately you're trying to enable [Name based virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) in Apache.  Both Tomcat and Wildfly have similar concepts.

Comment: I'm using this AMI: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00NN8XQWU  
 
I searched the machine for a2enmod and a2ensite and they aren't on the box.

I'll check out your link. I also found this that I'll dig into:  https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/apache/

Comment: @stdunbar -- I got it working - solution posted below.  Thanks for your guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those looking for something similar, here is the solution that worked for me.

My server is a Wildfly-Apache2-MySQL AMI image on AWS.  I did not need to use a2enmod nor a2ensite as my research suggested.  It seems many of those modules are already enabled by the pre-built image.

**NOTE THESE INSTRUCTIONS ARE BITNAMI AWI SPECIFIC - YOUR FLAVOR CONFIGURATION MAY BE SLIGHTLY DIFFERENT**

To have a subdomain point to a simple Apache text site (yada.example.com):

- Create a directory in ~/stack/apache2/htdocs called yada
- Add an entry to the virtual hosts configuration file (`sudo nano /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`)

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/yada"
    ServerName yada.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/yada-subdomain-error-log"
    CustomLog "logs/yada-subdomain-access-log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

- Modify the Apache configuration file to include the virtual hosts. (`sudo nano /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`):

```html
...snip...

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as
# necessary.
 
...snip...
 
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# ADDED THE ABOVE LINE

...snip...
```

- Restart Apache (`sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache`)

To make it point to a Tomcat server, add this to the `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@example.com
    ServerName yada.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
 
 
    # setup the proxy
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8090/
</VirtualHost>
```

Your port may differ.

FYI, I found this helpful:  https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/apache/#how-to-configure-your-web-application-to-use-a-virtual-host

Good luck and shout out to @stdunbar for his guidance.